# coverage.py ImportError: No module named coverage.cmdline

Tags: python, code-coverage

I use the coverage.py module periodically but every time I don't use it for more than a year I forget how to use it and it takes enormous amounts of time to figure out how to use it since the instructions posted at `https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.3.2/`have no bearing on reality and do not work.  The last time I wrote the instructions down but inspite of that I still cannot get it to work. The instructions that I used to use and that worked were:

```
coverage-3.8 run -m [module without .py] [args]
coverage-3.8 html -i
```

Now after some trial and error I have to use:

python -m coverage run [module with .py] [args]

That works but now when I try to generate the html report with

```
coverage html -i
```

I get

```
File "/usr/local/bin/coverage", line 7, in <module>
    from coverage.cmdline import main
ImportError: No module named coverage.cmdline
```

I have been able to generate the html report in the past and it has always been a simply command line function but I don't know why it doesn't work now.

Comment: "have no bearing on reality and do not work"... wow, that sounds really bad. :)

You don't mention what goes wrong when you use your old instructions.  It sounds like you have multiple Python installations, and/or a file named coverage.py in your local directory?

Comment: It worked this time, using the coverage-3.8 command.  Not sure what I was doing wrong the first time.

Answer (score -1):

Actually,

```
coverage-3.8 run -m [module without .py] [args]
coverage-3.8 html -i
```

are valid commands and will return the desired results.  I decided not to delete the post just in case anyone else has similar problems with coverage.py.